# How does one disable deprecated warnings in Flex 3?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, deprecated, suppress-warnings

I've recently started working with an application written using Adobe Flex 3.  We're using several deprecated functions and unfortunately we can't remove these dependencies.

The documentation says to set -show-deprecated-warnings=false into the Compiler Additional Options.  This isn't accepted, but I've found that using -show-deprecation-warnings=false will be accepted by the dialog, but gives an error about declaring the option twice when I try to compile the project.

Ideally, I'd like a way to disable the warning on a case-by-case basis.  Failing that, can anyone help me to disable the warnings either per-file, per-project or globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a partial workaround: filter the warnings from the 'Problems' tab.  This doesn't get rid of the next-to-the-source warning markers, but it's the Problems tab which I'd like to be clean.

Click the filters button on the Problems tab, change 'Description' to 'doesn't contain' with text 'deprecated' and hit OK.

Answer (score 2):

As an update for recent versions, I added a compiler option in FlashDevelop:

-show-deprecation-warnings=false

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This link suggests that it doesn't work properly anyway, and the only real answer is to turn off warnings altogether.

[Adobe Jira 13569](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-13569)

You can turn off warnings by using a custom flex-config.xml file for each project / globally. Just point the compiler at the right file.

Comment: Thank you, +1.  Not the answer I'd hoped for :(.  I have a partial workaround, see my own answer to the question.